# Can I say "awaken me from my naive view"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, writing, analogy

I found out that the same product tended to mean different things for different people. For one person, a lipstick brought confidence. For another, it was just a simple pigment. This experience *awakened me from my naïve view* that the lipstick of itself reignited my cousin’s passion for life. （Rather，？）It was the idea that she accepted from that advertisement of Maybeline that gave her inner strength.

I have heard the expression like "awaken me from my dream/ dogmatic dream", but I am not sure whether one can say "awaken from a naive view" or "...from a dogmatism". Is this analogy comprehensible?

Comment: I would suggest that your naive view is not like sleep, but like ignorance. How about "enlighten" you from a naive view?  Or, if it is seen as a misconception, you can say soneone is "disabused" of such a misconception.

Comment: Complicated expression with a picture that does not fit. You can say it simpler by asking: Is my view naive?

Comment: The view that you claim to be awakened from doesn't seem very naive. _reignited my cousin's passion for life_ is a pretty complex interpretation of lipstick.

Comment: Can you say that?  Definitely, unless you are mute for some reason.  Does it convey the meaning you intend?  That is much a harder to determine.

Comment: *Woke* is used to mean both aware of racial injustice (and other social problems), and aware that a partner is cheating on you ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woke)); and a "spiritual awakening" is something similar to the former sense. So it works as a metaphor.

Comment: It's a mixed metaphor. 'notion/s]'  ↔ 'view' (a physical vista in the first instance) // '[having] an unrealistic expectation/opinion [shattered]'   ↔  'being awakened from a fanciful dream'. While it's meaning is clear (and mixed metaphors can occasionally  be great fun), I'd choose to rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

Using *waken from* with *view* is not necessarily a bad thing. It would coerce the noun *view* to be taken as a form of slumber or revery. This may be a powerful tool or a clumsy one, depending on how it's handled.

Just remember that there are no real "rules" about writing except one: *does it work?* If it does, use it; if not, don't.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a flowery expression from someone with an exotic mother-tongue.

Comment: Perhaps it is in line with the context?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> This experience disabused me of my naïve view...

on for size.

Comment: Yes, I'd say this sounds less quirky.